# Editing my custom Vendor object

Tags: customization, auto-number

So, I'm trying to edit a custom object 'Current or Previous Vendor' page to display name of the actual vendor. As you can see from the screen-shot I've attached in this thread, it's displaying the auto-numbering "2". Instead of it displaying the number "2", I'd like it to display the name of the actual vendor. How do I edit this to display the name of the Vendor instead of the auto-numbering? Thanks for your time!

Screen-shot:

[image]

Comment: I think we need some additional information.  Is the vendor info coming from another object?  How is field "Current or Previous Vendor" defined?

Comment: I assume that it is a self lookup relationship but from the screenshot it looks like a record is pointing to itself which i believe is not supported.

Comment: Hi Jaqular, thanks for your reply! To answer your questions, the information in the "Current or Previous Vendor" object is not coming from another object and the field "Current or Previous Vendor" is an 'auto number' data type. Need anymore information?

Answer (score 1):

Is the autonumber field actually the name field? Custom objects in Saelsforce have a field which acts as the name for a record, and this is either free text or an autonumber field. It appears in this case that when the object was created the name field was set to number and that's why it's showing at the top of the page.

It sounds like what you want is to change the name field to be a text type, and then have a second custom autonumber field for other purposes. If you go to the configuration page for your object you should be able to click `Edit`next to the `Name` field and change it to a text type. Note that in doing this if you have data in production you'll likely need to migrate the data from the field to another one first.

[image: Name field settings]

Comment: Thanks for your response LaceySnr! That is correct that I'm looking for in to be a text field, but not where the user inputs the text. I would like it to be like a formula field, where the user cannot edit it and it displays the value='the name of the actual vendor'. instead of an automated number or a user inputted text. Is this possible? since the only two options for the field is Text or Auto Number? Is there anyway I could replace the field with a different one? Thanks again!

Comment: Afraid not, the name has to be one of those two types and that's what's displayed at the top. The only way around this would be to create a custom VF page to override the edit page but that's overkill for this situation. Perhaps a formula field that generates HTML to put a bold font or something as the first field on the page will be enough.

Answer (score 0):

you will have to create a additional field of type formula to be able to get the name of the vendor

Comment: Can I get that additional field(formula field you mention) to replace the field that I'm questioning about(currently the auto number field)?